# Sorting a list (with lambda) with a variable number of arguments

Tags: sorting, lambda, python-2.x

Given:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,1,1,1]]
```

How to sort `a` in place based on the sum of the values?

I tried using a lambda, but then it errors with a lambda not allowing a variable amount of arguments:

```
a.sort(lambda x: sum(x))
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 arguments (2 given)
```

The previous was a simplified example; I am actually trying to use another function that takes multiple arguments... this does change the problem.

```
a.sort(lambda x: len(my_function("123", x)))
```

Hopefully the answer can be done in base python.

Comment: The first argument to `sort` in Python 2 is `cmp`, not `key`. In Python 3, you get the error: `TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,1,1,1]]

a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: sum(x))

>>> print a
[[1,2], [1,1,1,1], [1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Awesome, this also handles the multiple arguments case!

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not "in place", but I guess that it does not matter. It is weird to me that using `a.sort()` it is not possible to get this working.

Comment: @PascalvKooten, You're right. I guess everything has tradeoffs. You want complex sorting parameters? Suffer a bit :) :P

Answer (score 5):

```
a.sort(key=sum)  # Need the 'key' keyword, and don't bother with lambda here.
```

is what you want.

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3]]
```

**EDIT:**

To fix the multiple argument example, just once again specify the `key` argument:

```
a.sort(key=lambda arg1, arg2, etc: function(arg1, arg2, etc))
```

Comment: It just needs to be: a.sort(key=sum)

Comment: My bad, but I'm actually using a *multiple argument function* rather than `sum`, is there a way to use key for that?

Comment: @PascalvKooten what is your function? I will edit answer to help if you tell me.

Comment: It is based on some path-finding algorithm. The number of arguments are variable, that is the issue (so you can't define "etc" to be one-fits-all)

Comment: Have you looked into `*args` @PascalvKooten ?

Comment: Yea, it did not work. Though now that I reconsider, I was probably missing the `key` argument. EDIT: I don't think I did

Comment: @PascalvKooten OK, with `*args` and the `key` argument it should work fine. If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it when you can? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,1,1,1]]
>>> print sorted(a, key=sum)
[[1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3]]
>>>
```